# How can SharePoint 2013 be used to administer objects to be lent to someone else?

Tags: 2013, calendar

Could SharePoint 2013 be used to administer devices that can be lent to customers like in a public library but with more complex objects and flexible rental durations?

It should be possible to

- create a list of the objects with their specific properties (it's about technical devices)
- have calendar-like views which show if a device is available or not at a certain day/time
- assign a SharePoint user to a device, if he has borrowed or booked it
- send messages about rentals and reminders to the people who have borrowed it, to give something back
- add notes to each rental

(I naively think this could be something like managing meeting rooms, each one has its calendar and can be booked by someone.)

Are the structures or frameworks in SharePoint which could be used to easily implement something like that? In general, it's about managing ressources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint can definitely do all what you asked. For each of your requirements, I'll indicate which SharePoint object/feature can accomplish it.

> - create a list of the objects with their specific properties

SharePoint lists

> - have calendar-like views which show if a device is available or not at a certain day/time

SharePoint calendars with filtered views

> - assign a SharePoint user to a device, if he has borrowed or booked it

A field AssignTo of type User, perhaps a custom Task list

> - send messages about rentals and reminders to the people who have borrowed it, to give
>     something back

SharePoint workflows and/or custom timer jobs

> - add notes to each rental

A field of type multiline text